# Remove duplicate object after compare 2 list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem to remove duplicate object in 2 list

```
public class Pump
{
    public int PumpID { get; set; }
    public string PumpName { get; set; }
    public string LogicalNumber { get; set; }
}

public void LoadPump()
{
    var pumps = _pumpRepository.GetAll(); // 2 Pump
    var pumpsActive = _pumpRepository.GetAllActive(); // 1 Pump Active (Pump 1)
    //i try like this
    List<Pump> pumpsNonActive = pumps.Except(pumpsActive).ToList(); // Result 2
    //if like this
    List<Pump> pumpsNonActive = pumpsActive.Except(pumps).ToList(); // Result 1 (Pump 1)
}
```

I want to get only 1 result in pumpsNonActive (Result = Pump 2). Anyone can help me :/

Comment: Your `Pump` class has to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods.

Comment: How your repository implement? how you manage DbContext?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could override `Equals` or you can try the following:

```
 List<Pump> pumpsNonActive = pumps.Where(r => !pumpsActive
                                             .Any(t => t.PumpID == r.PumpID))
                                  .ToList();
```

This worked for the following dataset:

```
List<Pump> pumps = new List<Pump>()
{
    new Pump() { PumpID = 1, LogicalNumber = "SomeName", PumpName="PumpName1"},
    new Pump() {PumpID = 2, LogicalNumber = "Number", PumpName = "PumpName2"},
    new Pump(){PumpID = 3, LogicalNumber = "Number", PumpName = "PumpName3"},
};

List<Pump> pumpsActive= new List<Pump>()
{
    new Pump() { PumpID = 1, LogicalNumber = "2", PumpName="3"},
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Habib its work! :)
And i change it to be like this :
List<Pump> lists = pumps.Where(p => activePumps.All(ap => ap.PumpID != p.PumpID)).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

Implement [`.Equals(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) and [`.GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx).

```
public class Pump
{
    public int PumpID { get; set; }
    public string PumpName { get; set; }
    public string LogicalNumber { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        var casted = o as Pump;
        if (casted == null)
            return false;

        return PumpID == o.PumpID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return PumpID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks its works too :)
Implement : var lists = pumps.Where(p => !activePumps.All(p.Equals)).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Imeplement

```
public class Pump: IEquatable<Pump>
{
     public bool Equals(Pump other)
     {
          ...
     }
}
```